# unable to create folder on /mnt via chef recipe

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-recipe, packer

I am using the following chef command to create a folder on /mnt

```
directory '/mnt/node/deploy' do
  owner 'ubuntu'
  group 'ubuntu'
  mode '0755'
  recursive true
  action :create
end
```

This is a part of a recipe which is invoked via packer to create an AWS AMI. `ubuntu` is the user that I use to deploy my code to a provisioned machine.
When I launch an EC2 instance using the AMI, this folder is not created on the machine. What could be the problem? I see no errors when the AMI is created.

Update -1

These are the logs. I tried using root.

```
`amazon-ebs: * directory[/mnt/node/deploy] action create`
`amazon-ebs: - create new directory /mnt/node/deploy`
`amazon-ebs: - change mode from '' to '0755'`
`amazon-ebs: - change owner from '' to 'root'`
`amazon-ebs: - change group from '' to 'root'`
```

I see that EC2 is mounting ephemeral storage on /mnt.
I want to create these folders on the ephemeral storage.
I unmounted /mnt, but did not see the folders there.

Comment: The directory creation seems correct. Could you please paste the full Chef log output? Maybe something is mounting there which would make the directory disappear.

Comment: I am suspecting this has something to do with ephemeral storage. EC2 seems to mount the ephemeral storage on /mnt.

Comment: Try umounting `/mnt` and check if the directory is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packer runs Chef before creating the image. So, if I understand you correctly:

1. Chef creates the directory on an instance ephemeral storage.
2. Packer creates the AMI.
3. You start the AMI and the directory does not exist in the ephemeral storage.

AFAIK that's an expected behavior. The directory is created in a partition that is ephemeral and this kind of partitions are not expected to endure.

Summarizing, when you create an AWS AMI image, it does not include the ephemeral storage. Only the EBS volumes. Ephemeral partitions are always empty at startup. If you want to retain that directory, it must be in a EBS partition.

If you still want to use the `/mnt` directory, you can avoid mounting the ephemeral storage with the [`ami_block_device_mappings`](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#ami_block_device_mappings) option:

```
  "ami_block_device_mappings": [
    {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdb",
      "no_device": true
    }
  ],
```

And the same for the [`launch_block_device_mappings`](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#launch_block_device_mappings)

Another solution could be to run your Chef cookbook again in the newly created instance.

Comment: /mnt is the place where ephemeral storage is loaded. The AMI creation process shuts down the instance which clears the ephemeral storage.

Answer (score 0):

`amazon-ebs` is the name of the packer builder:

> `amazon-ebs` - Create EBS-backed AMIs by launching a source AMI and
>   re-packaging it into a new AMI after provisioning. If in doubt, use
>   this builder, which is the easiest to get started with.

It runs the whole machine as EBS-backed so it can convert the EBS volume into an AMI later.

This is not related to Chef.